# JavaScript Regex exclude brackets

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I'm trying to make a simple validation in JavaScript & PHP (for double checking) by using regex. I just want to check that the names will be allowed if there is at least two of these characters:

letters + accents + spaces + simple quotes + dash

```
^[aA-zZ\u00C0-\u017F- \']{2,}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/hg1UZPY83Daraby4)

But actually, brackets are allowed in my regex pattern (don't know why), and I'd like them to be excluded, how can I do that ?

I know that \u is not allowed in PCRE-like regular expressions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets are between `A` and `z` I think you meant to have `a-zA-Z` in your regex.

Comment: Doest that mean I need to do something like that : ^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST\u00C0-\u017F- \']{2,}$ ? It's a bit ugly

Comment: No `^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F- \']{2,}$`

Comment: @Lazao: replace `aA-zZ` with `a-zA-Z`. Also note, in the screenshot there's a `-` in `A-z`, so you basically have a, then A to (lower case) z, then Z.